# What is Bloch-Floquet theory?

Tags: floquet-theory

And specifically Bloch-Floquet boundary conditions? I would love to hear any explanation you guys might have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floquet and Bloch's theorems : connection?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155466/)

Comment: Floquet theory is a theory of differential equations with periodic coefficients, see, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory). It has a particular application in crystals in a form of [Bloch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem), hence the double name. This question really lacks some prior research.

Answer (score 1):

[Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem) and [Floquet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) are the same thing. They are just given different names by physicists (Bloch) and mathematicians (Floquet).  These days physicsist have started using "Floquet" when the indepenedent variables is $t$ rather than $x$

They apply to systems of differential equations  with discrete translation symmetry such a periodic potentials (Bloch) or periodically varying driving forces (Floquet).  For a periodic potential one  seeks solutions of the form $\psi(x)= e^{ikx} U(x)$ where $u(x)$ is periodic with the same period as the potential. (This is the Bloch boundary condidion).

The Wikiedia links in the first paragarph should be eneough to get started.